Updating an existing Prompt Flow application in ai.azure.com (dependency conflicts)
I have a PromptFlow application in ai.azure.com (Microsoft's Azure AI Foundry) that I am developing locally in VS Code.
As you can imagine, I make changes in VS Code, test, and then upload them to my PF in Azure, re-test and then deploy.
Now and again, my extensions get updated, so this might include the Extension "Prompt Flow for VS Code" along with its dependencies (promptflow, promptflow-tools, promptflow-core, promptflow-devkit, promptflow-tracing, etc, etc).
So my question is, is there anything I need to do to update my Prompt Flow in Azure?  What's considered "best practice" here?
My understanding is that I don't need to push the .promptflow folder, since that holds local information for VS Code.  But what about the typings folder?
I ask because the other day I tried to start a compute session and got this error:

promptflow-runtime 20241115.0 requires waitress<4.0.0,>=3.0.1, but you have waitress 2.1.2 which is incompatible.

When I changed my requirements.txt file to include that, after saving and installing it then told me that:

promptflow-devkit 1.16.1 requires waitress<3.0.0,>=2.1.2

So I'm kinda stuck between a rock and a hard place because my version of waitress is either too new or too old.
Interesting that Azure says it's using promptflow-runtime 20241115.0.  It's not clear how I get my VS on a comparable version.  I am using the VS Code extension Prompt Flow for VS Code v1.20.2, and its dependencies are: promptflow 1.16.2, promptflow-tools 1.4.0, promptflow-core 1.16.2, promptflow-devkit 1.16.2 and promptflow-tracing 1.16.2.

And as suddenly as it appeared, the problem vanished (guessing MS fixed something)
